# Ubuntu 18.10 not working after installing NVIDIA GPU driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, 18.10

After I installed my GPU driver with the software updater I restarted my computer, when I launched Ubuntu my resolution for the logo was extremely bad, it started to start and finish the processes, then got stuck. Every time I try to use Ubuntu, my computer gets stuck, it won't even let me type commands! The only way out of this is to reinstall Ubuntu, and I don't want to do that again. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this or a way to install my GPU driver correctly. I'm new to Linux and don't know to a lot of the commands so please help.

*I figured out how to remove my NVIDIA driver, but my Ubuntu is still trying to use it and won't boot. Please talk to me in the comments.*

Comment: You can remove the nvidia drivers to at least get running by doing the following to remove the nvidia drivers.  From within grub, select Advanced Options for Ubuntu and then select Recovery. Once at the prompt use "sudo apt-get --remove nvidia-*"  When that finishes, reboot.    If grub doesn't automatically show up for you, I think holding down the right shift key will bring it up.

Comment: It's calling nvidia--* a invalid operation.

Comment: Do you know if i'm doing something wrong? I don't think I opened the prompt right.

Comment: There is only one - (dash) after nvidia and the dash is followed by *    I have two dashes before "remove".  If that doesn't work, you can try just one dash.  If you are getting to a prompt, you are in the probably in the correct place.  I don't know how else you would get to a prompt.

Comment: I removed nvidia driver but it still won't boot. If I find a reliable way to get my driver, I'll just reinstall Ubuntu. If you know how to install my driver I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Nvm, I just found out my Ubuntu is still trying to use my nvidia driver. Do you know how to undo this?